# Pass variable from applescript to executable bash file

Tags: bash, applescript

Is it possible to pass a variable from an applescript to an executable bash file?  If so, how do I write the executable bash file to accept parameters?  I'm going to be passing in a dynamic filename that will get appended to a file path in the executable file.

Applescript...

```
global A
set A to "test123.pdf"
do shell script "/Users/matt/firstscript " & A
```

Bash file...

```
#!/bin/bash
b64test=$( base64 /Users/matt/Documents/$1) 
echo $b64test | pbcopy
echo $b64test > Users/matt/Base64
```

Comment: Are you calling the bash script from within an applescript?

Comment: Yes, see above comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Applescript will need to do something like:

```
global A
set A to "test123.pdf"
do shell script "/Users/matt/firstscript " & A
```

Then in your script you can refer to the [parameters as `$1`, `$2`, etc, or `$@` for all of them.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Positional-Parameters)

```
#!/bin/bash

b64_test=$( base64 /Users/matt/Documents/$1)
echo $b64_test | pbcopy
echo $b64_test > /Users/matt/Base64
```

Note it is not a good idea to name your bash variable `test`, as this is the name of  shell builtin command.  All kinds of confusion can ensue.

---

Alternatively, you should be able to do this without an extra shell script:

```
set A to quoted form of "/Users/matt/Documents/test123.pdf"
do shell script "base64 " & A & " | pbcopy"
```

Comment: @StephenHammett - in general, it is better to edit your question, rather than post code in comments

Comment: @StephenHammett - see my edited answer - specifically I didn't realise at first you needed to pass the value of an applescript variable

Comment: @StephenHammett - also no need to ask another question - this one can be edited sufficiently to meet needs.

Comment: I made your recommended changes.  Please see above.

Comment: @StephenHammett - oops - its a `&` instead of a `+` needed to concatenate strings.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Using '&' in place of '+' is appending the value of A to the name of my shell script. "sh: /Users/matt/firstscripttest123.pdf: No such file or directory".   I want the value of A to be used where I have $1 in my shell script.

Comment: @StephenHammett - you need a space after the name of the script as in my answer.   This is just simple string concatenation, so you need to make sure the space is there between script name and parameters in the final command string, just as you would when invoking the command from the commandline.

Comment: I added in the extra space I missed before.  I'm not getting any errors now but my clipboard isn't getting set and the Base64 file is being filled with the base64.  Is there anyway to run a trace on the bash to see what parameters are coming in when the executable file is executed?  Its incredibly hard to debug without knowing exactly what or if anything is being passed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46956/discussion-between-digitaltrauma-and-stephen-hammett)